# My Apache 2 error log contains all error message lines splitted to individual characters

Tags: apache, curl, logging, process, stderr

I mean, all error messages is splitted into one character length, and these are the lines in my error_log. For example if the error message of my CGI application is "Error", I can see 5 lines of text, one line for every character of the error message, appended with referer and some other time informations. My error messages come from forked cURL process, and countains \r (carriage return) characters, because of the downloading progress indicator. What can I do to get the error output / stderr of my cURL processes really line-by-line?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I managed to find the solution with Popen3 from the stdlib:

```
require "open3"

cmd=%Q{curl -b cookie.txt 'http://www.example.com/file/afancyfileid/yetanotherfilename.avi' -L -O -J}

Open3.popen3(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  pid = wait_thr.pid # pid of the started process.
  line_no=0
  stderr.each_char do |c| 
       if c=="\r" then 
        line_no+=1
        STDERR.puts if line_no % 5 == 0
       else
        STDERR.print c if line_no % 5 == 0
       end
  end
  exit_status = wait_thr.value 
}
```

I print only every 5th lines not to let grow my error_log so fast.